# Building a desktop facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a Desktop Facebook application which will display the list of friends of a logged-in user. I am trying to do this using the Facebook javascript SDK. However when I open the HTML page, i get the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the Application
>   configuration. It must match one of the Connect or Canvas URLs or
>   domain must be the same as or a subdomain of one of the Application

I do understand that Facebook is asking for a URL from where this application will be called. However I would like to just run it by opening a HTML file from my local drive, rather than through a website. Is this possible to do?

There is a post on facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165982843535513/) which indicates that this might not be possible. However the post was made about 3 years ago. Is there a possible work around for this currently?

Answer (score 1):

You have to build a manual login flow:

> To use Facebook Login in a desktop app, you'll need to be able to
>   embed a web browser (sometimes called a webview) within the app to
>   perform the login process.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3

**Just in case you don´t know, you can only get friends who authorized your App too.**